# No value given for one or more required parameters error while deleting in database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2007

Every time I execute a DELETE query on my database, the following error results:

> No value given for one or more required parameters

I check the names but still have the error. Below is the code used to execute the query:

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
string query = "delete FROM Accounts WHERE Id_No = " + IdNoBox.Text + "";
command.CommandText = query;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Successfully Deleted");
this.Close();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Usually this means that one of your names (table or column) is mispelled and the engine thinks that it is a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Id_No to be string, it should be enclosed in single quotes.Otherwise, it will be considered as a parameter.
the query should `string query = "delete FROM Accounts WHERE Id_No = "'" + IdNoBox.Text + "'";`

Comment: If this were the problem then he will get a different error message. 'Data type mismatch'

Comment: my assumptions is if IdNoBox.Text is a string,

Comment: my assumptions is if IdNoBox.Text = is a string

Comment: string query = delete FROM Accounts WHERE Id_No = idno, the engine would assume idno to be a param, since idno has no quotes around. Any way, your comment makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

To address the specific question being asked, if Id_No is a character based, there should be single quotes around it. For readability, consider the following syntax.

```
string query = string.Format("delete FROM Accounts WHERE Id_No = '{0}' ", IdNoBox.Text);
```

Also note that the connection/command should be disposed of properly, including the cases where an exception occurs. An easy way to do this is with the using clause. See below.

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection())
using (var command = new OleDbCommand(){Connection = connection,CommandText = query})
{
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
MessageBox.Show("Successfully Deleted");
```

Comment: Different error pop up when i used this syntax. (missing operator) in query expression 'Id No = 1123".

Comment: Is there a space between Id and No?